# Why does FParsec not consume characters parsing a list separator?

Tags: f#, fparsec

*The actual scenario below is made up.  The purpose of the question is to understand more about what FParsec is doing here.*

I am parsing a list of the strings `(w)` and `(x)` that are separated by one or more space characters `' '`.

The parser for my list `xs` uses [`sepBy`](http://www.quanttec.com/fparsec/reference/primitives.html#members.sepBy) with a separator parser `isSeparator`.

`isSeparator` is based on [`manySatisfy`](http://www.quanttec.com/fparsec/reference/charparsers.html#members.manySatisfy) and seems to correctly consume spaces. I believe this can be seen in the test output below when it parses two leading space characters it ends at position 3.

However, it fails when I use it in `xs`, as shown below.

Why does this fail and what would be a good approach for dealing with a separator that could be one or more spaces?

```
open FParsec

let test p str =
    match run p str with
    | Success(result, _, p)   -> printfn "Success: %A position = %A" result p
    | Failure(errorMsg, _, _) -> printfn "Failure: %s" errorMsg

let str s = pstringCI s

let w = str "(w)"
let z = str "(z)"

let woz = w <|> z

let isSeparator = manySatisfy (fun c -> c = ' ')
let xs = sepBy woz isSeparator

test isSeparator "  (w)" // Success: "  " position = (Ln: 1, Col: 3)
test xs "(z) (w)"        // Failure: Error in Ln: 1 Col: 8
                         // (z) (w)
                         //        ^
                         // Note: The error occurred at the end of the input stream.                         
                         // Expecting: '(w)' (case-insensitive) or '(z)' (case-insensitive)
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure what the question is. The parser `xs` correctly parses `w` or `z` separated by a single space, because that's what you have specified as a separator. The parser `x2` should work as you expect: parsing `w` or `z` separated by multiple spaces.

Comment: Oh dear - my bad...the code is badly formed.  Will edit and update.  Thanks Fyodor Soikin.

Comment: Have now edited and updated the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens, because `manySatisfy` matches *zero or more* characters that satisfy the given predicate, the key word being "zero". This means that, at the very end of input, `isSeparator` actually succeeds, even though it doesn't consume any characters. And since `isSeparator` succeeds, `sepBy` is expecting to find another instance of `woz` after the separator. But there are no more instances, so `sepBy` returns an error.

To verify this, try parsing an input without spaces between `w` and `z`: `test xs "(z)(w)"`. This should print "Success", because empty separator is ok.

To make `isSeparator` always consume at least one character and fail when no spaces are found, use `many1Satisfy` instead of `manySatisfy`:

```
let isSeparator = many1Satisfy (fun c -> c = ' ')
let xs = sepBy woz isSeparator
```

Comment: After spending hours on  this today, "the key word being 'zero'" is a phrase that will stick in my mind!  Thank you.

Comment: Glad to help. :-)